# Как отсортировать map[string]int по значению?

Tags: сортировка, golang

Как отсортировать `map` в Go по убыванию значений?

Пример:

```golang
map[string]int{"value1": 10, "value2": 20,"value3": 30}
```

Comment: порядок ключей в мапе не определен. И поменять их местами нельзя (это не массив). Скорее всего нужно просто выводить - поэтому сортируйте и выводите.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну смотрите вы можете преобразовать `map` к массиву определенной структуры `[]struct` и потому использовать функцию [`sort.Slice`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Slice).

### Пример ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_t6c5kOIVTj)):

```
m := map[string]int{"value1": 10, "value2": 20,"value3": 30}

type key_value struct {
    Key   string
    Value int
}

var sorted_struct []key_value 

for key, value := range m {
    sorted_struct = append(sorted_struct , key_value {key, value})
}

sort.Slice(sorted_struct , func(i, j int) bool {
    return sorted_struct[i].Value > sorted_struct[j].Value
})

for _, key_value := range sorted_struct {
    fmt.Printf("%s, %d\n", key_value.Key, key_value.Value)
}
//OUTPUT:
//value3, 30
//value2, 20
//value1, 10
```

Преобразовать отсортированный массив определенной структуры к `map`, можно следующим образом.

### Преобразование `[]struct` к `map`

```
yourMap := structs.Map(sortedStructArray)
```

Но для этого надо подключить пакет [**`structs`**](https://github.com/fatih/structs).

Comment: У вас имена [не по стандарту](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#mixed-caps). Должен быть КамелКейс.

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Proper пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Мапы в го [не имеют определённой сортировки](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types).

> A map is an unordered group of elements of one type, called the element type, indexed by a set of unique keys of another type, called the key type. (…)

Вам надо будет достать все значения и ключи и отсортировать их с помощью пакета `sort`:

```
m := map[string]int{"value1": 10, "value2": 20, "value3": 30}
type kv struct {
    k string
    v int
}
kvs := make([]kv, 0, len(m))
for k, v := range m {
    kvs = append(kvs, kv{k, v})
}
sort.Slice(kvs, func(i, j int) bool {
    return kvs[i].v > kvs[j].v
})
fmt.Println(kvs)
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/bk8vaGJRiou.

Comment: @NikitaSmith Это две разные структуры данных. Вот придёт Go 2.0, сами напишем.

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

Примеры очень похожи, практически идентичны, но!
В одном случае создание слайса структур выполнено

`var  sorted_struct []key_value`
а во втором

`kvs := make([]kv, 0, len(m))`

Как лучше? Второй? Ведь если мы знаем размер, то наверное лучше указать?